# Sending NMEA to Android device over TCP/IP

Tags: android

I have Android device without integrated GPS module. Also I have external GPS which can send me NMEA messages over TCP/IP. I would like to use location services on this Android device for example for Navionics. The question - how to pass received NMEA messages to this application?
So emulate GPS device but over network. Android can link GPS over Blutooth, so I hope I can write an application to make same think with network data. Please advise.

Comment: If I guess right you need to root your device and implement a custom driver.

Answer (score 0):

Such apps use Mock Location Provider, I dont think that it is possible to create virtual bluetooth GPS. [Check this App.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rbc.gpsbridge&hl=ru)